# File::Find can't cd

Tags: perl

Using the `find()` function provided by `File::Find` I run into an unexpected exit. I localized the problem to be in the file `Find.pm` in `_find_dir($$$)` function at those lines :

```
die "Can't cd to $tmp from $dir_name"
unless chdir ($tmp);
```

I printed out `$tmp` and `$dir_name`. `$tmp` is `../..` and `$dir_name` is a 255 char full path(`d:\first_dir\second_dir\...\last_dir`). Is there any way I could overpass this limitation? ( I still want to get the full paths, so the `no_chdir` option for the `find()` function is excluded).

Also by changing the directory from command line to that 255 path and trying to run `cd ../..` fails with the message `The filename or extension is too long.`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Yes, it's a full path

Comment: I am assuming this is on Windows, and you are running into one of the many limitations of `perl` using ANSI versions of Win32 API functions.  You may instead want to give [Win32::LongPath](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::LongPath) a try while specifying `no_chdir` in `find`.

Comment: @SinanÜnür correct assumming. I will give it a try, but as I specified in my question, I can't use no chdir, since in the current architecture(an ancient one), we use full paths.

Comment: I don't understand. You are saying something like because the ocean temperatures are cold, I can't go skiing in the Alps. Maybe it makes complete sense, but there is no relevant information in your post that would put that statement in a meaningful context. You should be able to use `chdirL` provided by the module in your `wanted`.